# Definition of “cut”

Tags: meaning

Cut
2. To separate into parts with or as if with a sharp-edged instrument; sever: cut cloth with scissors.

According to the dictionary, if some paper is partially or half cut (which means there are no separate parts), we cannot describe it as “the paper is cut” but should describe it as “the paper is half-cut” or “the paper is partially cut” because there are no ‘parts’?

https://papernautic.com/craft/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/walk-through-paper-trick-02.jpg

[image]

I’ve posted related question before, but I can’t find where it’s posted.

Comment: Those are cuts. The paper is cut, just not all the way across.

Comment: In BrEng, if you are [half-cut](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/half-cut), you are drunk. Which might explain your failure to fully cut the paper...

Comment: Might be worth adding the dictionary link for your definition (assuming it's online). I suspect there are other definitions which cover this case. Just Googling, I find: "make an opening, incision, or wound in (something) with a sharp-edged tool or object", which applies here: the cuts you show are incisions.

Comment: @Michael Harvey I thought “incision” is only used for medical situation.

Comment: The word 'incision' is used by doctors, However, the use of the word is not confined to them. Cambridge Dictionary: incision noun an opening that is made in something with a sharp tool, **especially** in someone's body during an operation. 'Especially' does not mean 'exclusively'.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is still a cut even if it doesn't sever the item into two parts. For example, a "paper cut" is a cut caused by a piece of paper, usually on one's finger; it certainly doesn't sever the finger into two parts. I don't know where you got that definition of "cut", but [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cut) is "to penetrate with or as if with an edged instrument".

Comment: I thought “penetrate” only means ‘go through like a bullet’

Comment: @user09827 Perhaps you should use a better dictionary. The common definition of "penetrate" is much broader.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that the paper is `slit` or the paper is `slit` from the middle.

As verbs, the difference between `slit` and `cut` is that `slit` is to cut a narrow opening while `cut` is to perform an incision on or an opening resulting from cutting.

For example,
Let's say you have a banana. If you *cut* the banana in half, you'll get two pieces. If you *slit* the banana, you still have one piece, but now this has a small opening in it which is called a *slit*.

To be honest there isn`t much of a difference between these two words
but I hope this helped:)

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: But you can still cut a slit in a banana without cutting it in half.  Slit is an uncommon verb in my experience, much more frequently used as a noun.

Comment: There's a _tongue twister_ that high school students tend to pass around involving slit sheets.  Oddly, when I hear "slit", that's what I think of (_The sheet is slit.  Whoever slit the sheet is a sheet slitter_).  Other than describing artifacts in women's clothes, you don't hear the word _slit_ very often.

Comment: @Flydog57 Alternatively, _Sixteen sheets slit by Sam the Sheet Slitter._ :-)